# How can I sum multiple columns by rows in a dataframe?

Tags: r, apply, rowsum

How can I sum the columns (C1.dn + C2.dn + V1.dn + V2.dn) by each row and display it as a new column in the same dataframe?

For example, sum of row 1 (9.659531 + 5.159067 + 9.220461 + 13.48245) should be displayed as a new column (37.52).

A snippet of my data is provided below.

```
 C1.dn     C2.dn    V1.dn    V2.dn
1   9.659531  5.159067 9.220461 13.48245
2  13.482264 15.033321 5.249731 15.39126
3  14.986702  8.004261 8.190506 12.43744
4  16.130656 16.455435 7.469901 11.58376
5  11.597134  8.422198 5.798567 12.34388
6  14.337659 15.216855 5.883851 10.27983
7  11.403534  7.947642 7.051602 16.54026
8  20.604107 14.437914 5.023191 12.63318
9  11.324600  7.044436 6.866096 13.99970
```

Thanks.

Comment: `rowSums` will be helpful

Comment: `df$new_col <- rowSums(df)`

Comment: @RonakShah, how about if the df has more columns than these? Including factor, character etc. Thanks.

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52075773

Answer (score 0):

```
dat <- read.table(text = " C1.dn     C2.dn    V1.dn    V2.dn
1   9.659531  5.159067 9.220461 13.48245
2  13.482264 15.033321 5.249731 15.39126
3  14.986702  8.004261 8.190506 12.43744
4  16.130656 16.455435 7.469901 11.58376
5  11.597134  8.422198 5.798567 12.34388
6  14.337659 15.216855 5.883851 10.27983
7  11.403534  7.947642 7.051602 16.54026
8  20.604107 14.437914 5.023191 12.63318
9  11.324600  7.044436 6.866096 13.99970", header = T)


dat
dat$newcol <- rowSums(dat)

> dat
      C1.dn     C2.dn    V1.dn    V2.dn   newcol
1  9.659531  5.159067 9.220461 13.48245 37.52151
2 13.482264 15.033321 5.249731 15.39126 49.15658
3 14.986702  8.004261 8.190506 12.43744 43.61891
4 16.130656 16.455435 7.469901 11.58376 51.63975
5 11.597134  8.422198 5.798567 12.34388 38.16178
6 14.337659 15.216855 5.883851 10.27983 45.71820
7 11.403534  7.947642 7.051602 16.54026 42.94304
8 20.604107 14.437914 5.023191 12.63318 52.69839
9 11.324600  7.044436 6.866096 13.99970 39.23483
```

As stated in your comment, if data contains columns that are non-numeric, you can do the following

```
iris$newcol <- apply(iris, 1, FUN = function(x)sum(as.numeric(x), na.rm = T))

> head(iris)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species newcol
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa   10.2
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa    9.5
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa    9.4
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa    9.4
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa   10.2
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa   11.4
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but my dataframe has more than these four columns (including factor, character etc). When done your way, it says "x should be numeric".

Comment: @Pranav_b You can use the following code for as many columns as possible:
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(sum_row = sum(c_across(C1.dn:V2.dn)))

Comment: @Pranav_b, so in that case, would you like to sum only numeric columns?